# Google Drive API is rate limited?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have ~220GB that I've been trying to get onto Drive for a while.  Web/Mac official clients can't handle it without constant supervision and manual intervention, so I was super happy to come across a command line tool that uses the Drive API.  It uploaded about 20GB in 2 days just fine (kinda slow) but then suddenly dropped to 1KB/sec upload speed.  What happened?  I can't get it to go back up and the estimated time to complete is now over 1000 hours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to speak to the author of the command line tool.

Drive throttles all write operations and it's up to the software to manage that correctly for maximum throughput. In extreme cases you may need to parallelize your uploads over multiple user accounts.